# Video host URL different in full content page links than in View links

Tags: uri

**Background:** Site in question has a custom content type "video record" containing many custom fields including a URL to brightcove.com-hosted video. (Note, the site is *not* using any Brightcove-specific modules.) A thumbnail image activates the link in both the full content view of a page and also in a View displaying a smaller selection of the fields from this content type. In both cases, the link is opened in a modal window generated by the module "lightbox2."

**Problem:** Thumbnail links from the View work as intended. Links from the full content page *do not* work, although they were working at an earlier point in site development. Unfortunately we don't know at what exact point, in the course of core or module updates, this functionality was lost.

**Additional Info:** Looking at the links in Firebug, we see an obvious difference: The ones that work (from the View of fields drawn from this content type) include a string beginning with "bcpid1235797793001?bckey= ..." and ending with a string of type "&secureConnections=true&secureHTMLConnections=true" that exists in the URL field of every node of this type. The ones that don't work are lacking both strings.

**The Question:** The link in the View and the one in the full content page must draw from the same URL field, as there is only one such field for each content item. In the case of the full content type, why might it be stripping out parts of the original URL and delivering a result that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install the Dev version of module Image Link Formatter (7.x-1.0+6-dev). It now seems clear, this module (the current recommended version) was invisibly rewriting the URL, as there is no other way it could be specified to be rewritten in the standard interface options for the content type's fields. Although there was no documentation found for this issue in the issue queue or in documentation about the Dev version, apparently it is a bug that was fixed.